# How can I switch out of "Internal Beta" version in Android App Store?

Tags: google-play-store

I'd like to install the most recent public version of an app I'm working on. I also happen to be a beta tester.

The page for the app in the Android Play Store has many tells that it is for the internal beta:

> You're an internal tester. This app may be insecure or unstable.

How do I switch out of this without removing myself from the beta tester list?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to go back to the public version, you just have to leave the beta program. Leaving the beta program is done using the page for the application in the Google Play Store. Open the page of the app in the Google Play Store, and scroll down till you something like "You're a beta tester". Just below that title, there should be a button "Leave". Pressing that button will bring you back to the general public version.

Watch out, because some apps don't work that good if you want to go back in version numbers. Could be you have to reinstall the app afterwards.

Comment: `"without removing myself from the beta tester list"`.  I suppose it is not yet possible then.

Comment: The only way is by removing yourself from the beta tester list as far as I know. You can probably go back to the beta if you want after going to the public version?

Answer (score 1):

One other thing that could prevent getting out of Beta is if you enabled Developer Options on your phone. You have to go to Settings -> System -> Developer Options -> Use developer options (turn off). After that if you already left beta testing group, the app should now show up as non-Beta in Play Store.

Comment: Based on my experience, Developer Options isn't really related to the Google Play Beta program, but this answer might tell a different story.

Comment: I used to have a "leave" option for internal testing in the GP store app, but can no-longer find it.

The only way for me to get back to the prod version was by following the above suggestion (disable developer options on my Samsung Galaxy A7 tablet).

I'd tried removing myself from our internal test list, and restarted device, but that alone didn't pull me out of the internal test track.  After disabling developer options, and app-switching back to the GP store w/our app open, it auto-refreshed w/o the internal test verbiage, and was able to install the prod version w/o issue.

Comment: Neither work for me - I have no Leave option, and turning of Developer options didn't affect which version of the app I had installed. Even after uninstalling, it still comes with the warning "You're an internal tester. This app may be unsecure or unstable". And when I install it installs an internal beta version that isn't compatible with the production environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the developer console, you can download the most recent public version's APK and install it on your device manually. Type in "App Bundle Explorer" in the search bar at the top of the developer console and you will be able to pick the version to download the APK for. Once you install it on your device, you can test it and then also test upgrading to the version available to the internal testers.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the app from the Play Store.

Then browse the beta tester invitation web page you have received by email when you apply to be a beta internal-tester. There is a blue button link to leave the beta.

The page url looks like [https://play.google.com/apps/internaltest/[some-numeric-id]](https://play.google.com/apps/internaltest/%5Bsome-numeric-id%5D)

You can find the page link at Google Play Console > Your app > Tests > Internal tests > Testers tab > "Copy link" at the bottom.

Then install the app again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just delete myself from the list of users for the internal test from the Play Console.
Then I uninstall the app and delete the cache only.
Then I get (Internal Beta)" removed.